# Is the Android F-Droid client still actively maintained?

Tags: updates, f-droid, freeware

According to the [G-Droid app description on the F-Droid website](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.gdroid.gdroid/), "the F-Droid client is not [actively maintained] any more".

I could not find evidence that this is true.

Is the Android F-Droid client still actively maintained?

Comment: Given the update history of F-Droid, 
it seems to be actively updated.  https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.fdroid.fdroid/

Comment: The app has asked me to update it at least 3 times in the past week.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Hmmm... something doesn't sound right on your end.  According to the link Firelord posted, the app hasn't been updated since the first week of this year.

Comment: Remember that apps are presented that are compatible with your device and its capabilities. In spite of F-Droid version currently at 1.5.1, my device reports 1.4 as the latest available compatible version. It is also dependent on the app signature, which may not be upgradeable from the source you are currently viewing. Possibly the app was originally installed from some other distribution line, which is no longer maintained. Perhaps an uninstall/re-install from your desired repository would allow 1.5.1 for you?

Comment: I just performed the last statement in my former comment: Uninstall/Reinstall, and now have v1.5.1, updated repositories, and reports of updates to other apps, which didn't report with v1.4. Clearly, provenance matters when using this app installer and repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [F-Droid get's updates and commits.](https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidclient/-/commits/master/)

[G-Droid does not get commits anymore.](https://gitlab.com/gdroid/gdroidclient/-/commits/master/)

The message by G-Droid was removed in [`d53a33c8`](https://gitlab.com/gdroid/gdroidclient/-/commit/d53a33c899c014a5834897bbac1bba0e8c5be813#fcaedd05888d2b31a261842a39efb08d3f407459_36_27%5D)

Comment: Thank you.  Great find with the commit removing that message (and ironically stating that G-Droid is actively maintained).